# Is there a specific R or python code to solve the below besides pnorm?

Tags: r, readr

Let X ~ N (100, 202). Find two values, a and b, symmetric about the mean, such that the probability of the random variable taking a value between them is 0.99

I've used the below to look for the z-value 
pnorm(0.005)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide more precision? What does `pnorm` compute exactly? You might be looking for the inverse of `pnorm`. Have a look at `qnorm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple function implementing an inverse transformation from z-score to a normal variate.

```
cinorm <- function(p = 0.95, mean = 0, sd = 1){
  q <- c((1 - p)/2, p + (1 - p)/2)
  z <- qnorm(q)
  x <- mean + sd*z
  x
}

cinorm(0.99, 100, 202)
#[1] -420.3175  620.3175
```

Comment: Nice one, which makes it more explicit and implicitly also adds the information that the OP is looking for the confidence interval :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This explains it well.

Answer (score 2):

For a standard normal distribution, mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1, this is `qnorm(0.005, mean = 0, sd = 1)` and `qnorm(0.9995, mean = 0, sd = 1)`, respectively. So you just need to rescale it to your defined normal distribution. Let me know if you've defined the variance or standard deviation.